# overridePendingTransition & addView with LayoutTransitions

Tags: android, android-animation, layouttransition

I am in a situation where I want to have no visible animation during a transition between Activities. I am currently doing the following:

```
startActivity( intent );
getActivity().overridePendingTransition( 0, 0 );
```

Works fine. Once in the second Activity, I want to animate LayoutTransitions (for better or for worse) -- specifically, calling `addView()` on the root view coupled with `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in XML.

Right now, `addView()` is being called in my `onResume()` of the second Activity and shows no LayoutTransition animations (just pops the added view in place). I'm guessing that either `overridePendingTransitions(int, int)` or `startActivity()` (and thus the override as well) are "in effect" until some specified lifecycle event occurs in the second Activity. But I can't find this information. Should I just assume that it's until the end of `onResume()`?

Removing a View later, say when the user presses the back button, triggers the LayoutTransition animation fine. But this is unrelated to the Activity lifecycle.

So my question is, at what point does `overridePendingTransition( 0, 0 )` release control of animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release of `overridePendingTransition` is not associated with any lifecycle event.

`overridePendingTransition` will release control after the duration of animation is completed.
That is,  `300 ms` (default duration) or `user specified duration` (set in XML or using setDuration())

For no visible animation during a transition between Activities, use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)

instead of `overridePendingTransition`

> intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
>   startActivity( intent );

Comment: The intent flag didn't work for me, though it's something I've overlooked before now. The default duration information is great, thanks for that! I'm not happy with my implementation in general, so I may not have this problem after all.